# Is there a formula for present value of a growing annuity with yearly payment growth and monthly payments?

Tags: present-value, annuity

I have seen formulas that have cracked the future value of growing annuity where there are monthly payments and yearly growth rates.

But given a future value, is it possible to derive the present value of annuity that is monthly in nature and grows on a yearly basis.

E.g. I want a retirement corpus of say $1,000,000 in 2040. What should be my monthly savings over the next 24 years such that monthly savings amount grows by 5% every year. The rate or return can be assumed to be 3%

Answer (score 1):

A simple query on google could have given you the answer...

Let's define

- lumpsum *q*
- periodic contribution *a*
- *y* periods
- a periodic rate *i*

$$q*(1+i)^y + a(  ((1+i)^y-1) / i ) - a = f$$

Suppose we do not want an initial investment $q=0$.

2040 - 2016 = 24 years. As you want to know the monthly contribution, everything needs to be converted to months. Thus 24 years equals $y=288$ months.

The 5% yearly return needs to be converted to a monthly return as well. $1,05^{1/12} - 1 = i=0.4\% $.

Finally let's put a monthly contribution of $a=\$1857.66$.

Putting that in the formula gives us +/- $1,000,000.

By rearranging the formula, we isolate the contribution amount *a*

$$a = (i * (f -q*(i+1)^y))/((i+1)^y-i-1)$$

which gave us a monthly contribution of $1857.66

Comment: I am looking out for the following: In the case above, the answer would be something like: 1500 monthly savings for 1st year,  (1500 * 1.05) monthly savings for 2nd year and so on such that in the 24th year the FV is $1M. The savings in itself should grow at 3% every year.